# How can I use namespaced collections with Mongoid?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I need to have collections such as:

- client1.users
- client1.images
- client2.users
- client2.images

MongoDB supports Collection namespacing.  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections

Using the Ruby driver for MongoDB that won't be a problem but I want to have an ODM.

How can I use namespace collections with Mongoid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your models into namespaces with Mongoid. You will have to specify the fully qualified class_name in any associations that you define, e.g.

```
module Client1
  class Image
    include Mongoid::Document
    referenced_in :user, :inverse_of => :images, :class_name => 'Client1::User'
  end

  class User
    include Mongoid::Document
    references_many :images, :inverse_of => :user, :class_name => 'Client1::Image'
  end
end
```

Mongoid will map these two classes to MongoDB collections client1_images and client1_users respectively.

Comment: I need to do this dynamically because there could be a big number of clients.

Comment: I suppose it would be possible in Ruby to generate these modules and classes dynamically with Module.new or module_eval. Thats not something I have ever tried to do with Mongoid model classes and I don't know how well that would scale if you had a very large number. It would be more conventional to make Client a Mongoid::Document and define associations between Client and User (or whatever is appropriate to the domain) - I don't know your requirements.

Comment: Basically is a multitenant application. I have one single application server and this server uses one database. I want isolate the data from different clients by namespacing the collections. That could be done using the ruby driver quite easily, but I would rather have validations and other ODM sugar that Mongoid gives.